# Does the RemoteIE EdgeHTML engine render sites just like the Edge Browser on Windows 10?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, browser-support, modern.ie

I'm using the RemoteIE application (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/remote/) to render a HTML page that contains a CSS3 SVG animation. Just like in IE11, the animation does not work. In the last versions of firefox & chrome the animation works just as expected.

But this info (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg124132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that "Microsoft Edge enhances SVG functionality with support for new features. For example in Microsoft Edge, SVGpresentation attributes: are now animatable with CSS Animations and CSS Transitions."

On the other hand, the info of the RemoteIE app says "This version of Internet Explorer is modified to host the latest preview version of the EdgeHTML rendering engine, so you can test how your site will render in Microsoft Edge."

So, the question is: Does the RemoteIE app renders sites just like Microsoft Edge, or there are differences?

Answer (score 2):

RemoteIE uses a version of edgehtml (MS Edge's rendering engine) prior to the Windows 10 November update so there are quite a few differences and bugs we've fixed since.

If you want to test Edge the best option right now is to download one of the  free VMs we offer in the same website.